# UIViewController not keeping state in Storyboard

Tags: ios, design-patterns, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have a iOS5 storyboard app and am using it to push a view controller 'B' onto the navigation stack when a particular button is pressed in the initial view controller 'A'. After the button press 'B' gets loaded with some data pulled from a Web Service.

When the user hits the back navigation button and then presses the button to go to back to 'B', B has been completely reset. I understand that this the Storyboard recreating the ViewController B. How do I stop this from happening? I'm looking for the right design pattern to solve this problem.

Comment: Please somebody help.

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify why this happens. As soon as you hit the back button, the viewController 'B' is pushed off the stack and thus removed from memory. In order to avoid this, you will have to create a strong pointer property to the viewController 'B' in your AppDelegate. Then in viewWillAppear, you check to see if this property is null, and if it is you set its values normally. If it is not, then you know that you already have the viewController ready, and you use that instead.

Comment: What if I keep a pointer to controller B in controller A? I don't want to list a lot of controllers centrally in the App Delegate. Is

Comment: If you wish controller B to retain it's state throughout your entire application, then the correct place to have the property is in your AppDelegate. You could do as you describe there, but then if controller A is pushed off the stack, both controller A and B will be released from memory.